# Running pysparkling-water using Livy spark failed

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I have been able to run the ChicagoCrimeDemo.py script using spark-submit successfully (spark-submit --master=yarn-client --py-files /opt/sparkling-water-1.6.10/py/build/dist/h2o_pysparkling_1.6-1.6.10-py2.7.egg /opt/sparkling-water-1.6.10/py/examples/scripts/ChicagoCrimeDemo.py) .

Although when I try to execute the same script using Livy(Spark), I am getting the following error: [image]

Comment: don't think we tested it with Livy, is there any way to get more logs to figure out what exactly failed?

Comment: Hi Mateusz, Could you point out the files and file location that you need?

Comment: Any kind of Livy/yarn log files would be useful - we need to pinpoint what exactly failed.